# WKWebView causing issues on Android (cannot load local templates)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, wkwebview

I'm preparing to migrate my ionic-v1 app from UIWebView to WKWebView.

Everything works well on iOS but I'm facing issues with android. Specifically, it can't seem to load my local HTML templates

[image]

My CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * blob: android-webview-video-poster: cdvphotolibrary:  'self' data: ws: wss://*; default-src * blob: 'self' gap: wss: ws: data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * http: https: ws: wss:;">
```

My `allow-navigation`:

`<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />`

ionic info:

```
 ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
    Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.5

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
    Node              : v6.11.2
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```

I am on the latest wkwebview plugin:
`cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"`

Comment: Those urls don't have localhost on them. Can you give more details about how do you do the template loading?

Comment: Sure. It's a standard ionic v1 app. https://github.com/pliablepixels/zmNinja/blob/webview/www/index.html#L105   - works in iOS after I updated to wk. Thanks

Comment: And template linking is here:https://github.com/pliablepixels/zmNinja/blob/webview/www/js/app.js#L2305

Comment: @jcesarmobile would you prefer I file this in the wkwebview issue repo? Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I cloned that project and couldn't even build. Can you provide a simple sample project where this can be easily reproduced? Or at least provide build instructions in that repo (not sure if it's yours). I did `npm install` and `ionic build android` and it fails. Fixed a few things but other things kept comming

Comment: It looks like there is a conflict with WKWebview and `cordova-plugin-certificates` which allows us to access sites with self signed certs. Working on it. Besides that WKWebview is a royal pain, even mainstream APIs like medium feeds with JSON format error out due to Access Control headers missing. I can't use advanced-http cordova plugin because I also use img src for streaming images that needs to be in-browser (advanced http doesn't work for streaming images). What a mess.